# Access VBA - using a string (from a function) to add items to combobox

Tags: string, function, vba, combobox

I have a sub which will add items to a combobox from a Recordset as follows:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim funcReturn As String

strSQL = "SELECT supplier_id, supplier_name FROM suppliers"

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

With cboTest
    .RowSourceType = "Value List"
    .BoundColumn = 1
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;5cm"
End With

With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        cboTest.AddItem !supplier_id & ";" & !supplier_name '############
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Simple enough so far, and that works beautifully BUT.... I have a function which will return the below line as a string:

```
cboTest.AddItem !supplier_id & ";" & !supplier_name
```

My function will take in the SQL string and combobox name given, and then output a string similar to the above, and is called as below:

```
funcReturn = addRecordsetToComboboxString(strSQL, "cboTest")
```

So I want to run the variable funcReturn as a command. I've tried using eval and scriptcontrol, but I'm not having any luck so far.

I'm a beginner at this, and I've searched forums all day and can't get anything working.

Any help would be so appreciated!

Thank you,

James

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here: if you want a generic "populate a combobox from a SQL statement" sub, then this is a difficult way to implement it. For example, it's much harder to parse out "cboTest" from that string than it is to use `Me.Controls("cboTest")` to directly reference the control.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your input. The idea is that the SQL query and combobox name may change as the function will be used to populate queries from different forms. I can populate a combobox from an SQL query no problem, my question is how to turn this string into an actual command that will run. I don't know what you mean by parsing out the "cboTest", but I will try to directly reference the control as you suggested and update if I get there. Even so, if anyone could shed any light on my original problem, or show me how to even change my code to do that, then that would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I mean - easier to create a generic function to populate a combobox given a reference to that control and a SQL statement:

```
Sub PopulateCombo(cbo As Object, sql as string)

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection,rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i as Long, s as string

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    With rs
       .MoveFirst
       Do Until .EOF
          s=""
          For i = 1 to rs.Fields.Count
              s = s & IIf(i=1, "", ";") & rs.Fields(i).Value
          Next i
          cbo.AddItem s           
          .MoveNext
       Loop
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Usage:

```
PopulateCombo cboTest, "SELECT supplier_id, supplier_name FROM suppliers"
```

Comment: Tim, thank you, good Sir, you have solved my problem and I thank you wholeheartedly. Cheers!!!!!